# Excel-VBA: Using variables in Query

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to read data from several CSV-files. It works fine, but there is one issue I'm working on right now. Each CSV has a different structure an amount of columns. I already count the columns and the works well. Now I try to get the column type (text, number, int...) right. I know the following code to get the column type:

```
Dim ColNames() As String
ReDim ColNames(1 To CountCols)
Dim ColTypes As String
ColNames = Split(CSVline, ";")
ColTypes = ""
ColTypes = ColTypes & "    #""""Type wijzigen"""" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""""De eerste rij als veldnamen gebruiken"""",{"
For CT = LBound(ColNames) To UBound(ColNames)
    ' ID
    If InStr(ColNames(CT), "ID") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    ' Type
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Type") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    ' Assembly code en description
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Assembly") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    ' Width
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Width") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Breedte") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", Int64.Type}, "
    ' Length
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Length") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Lengte") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Perimeter") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", Int64.Type}, "
    ' Height
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Height") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Hoogte") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", Int64.Type}, "
    ' Area
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Area") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Oppervlak") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type number}, "
    ' Volume
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Volume") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type number}, "
    ' Phasing
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Phase") > 0 > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Fase") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    ' Weight
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Kilo") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "kg") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Ton") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Gewicht") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type number}, "
    ' Level
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Level") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Verdieping") > 0 > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Bouwlaag") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    ' Other
    Else
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    End If
Next CT
ColTypes = Left(ColTypes, Len(ColTypes) - 2)
ColTypes = ColTypes & "})"" & Chr(13) & """" & Chr(10) & ""in"" & Chr(13) & """" & Chr(10) & ""    #""""Type wijzigen"""""""
```

After this I have the variable `ColTypes` witch I want to put in to the query like

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="" & CSV(S) & "", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Bron = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & csvPath & CSV(S) & ".csv""),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=" & CountCols & ", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""De eerste rij als veldnamen gebruiken"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Bron, [PromoteAllScalars=true])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & ColTypes
```

When `ColTypes` is set empty, than the codes works perfect, when `ColTypes` is filled by above code my table gives an error at `.refresh backgroundquery:=false`

The complete code:

```
Dim ColNames() As String
ReDim ColNames(1 To CountCols)
Dim ColTypes As String
ColNames = Split(CSVline, ";")
ColTypes = ""
ColTypes = ColTypes & "    #""""Type wijzigen"""" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""""De eerste rij als veldnamen gebruiken"""",{"
For CT = LBound(ColNames) To UBound(ColNames)
    ' ID
    If InStr(ColNames(CT), "ID") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    ' Type
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Type") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    ' Assembly code en description
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Assembly") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    ' Width
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Width") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Breedte") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", Int64.Type}, "
    ' Length
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Length") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Lengte") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Perimeter") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", Int64.Type}, "
    ' Height
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Height") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Hoogte") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", Int64.Type}, "
    ' Area
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Area") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Oppervlak") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type number}, "
    ' Volume
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Volume") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type number}, "
    ' Phasing
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Phase") > 0 > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Fase") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    ' Weight
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Kilo") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "kg") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Ton") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Gewicht") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type number}, "
    ' Level
    ElseIf InStr(ColNames(CT), "Level") > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Verdieping") > 0 > 0 Or InStr(ColNames(CT), "Bouwlaag") > 0 Then
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    ' Other
    Else
        ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    End If
Next CT
ColTypes = Left(ColTypes, Len(ColTypes) - 2)
ColTypes = ColTypes & "})"" & Chr(13) & """" & Chr(10) & ""in"" & Chr(13) & """" & Chr(10) & ""    #""""Type wijzigen"""""""

Set CSVfile = Nothing
Set CSVobj = Nothing

' Set query
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="" & CSV(S) & "", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Bron = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & csvPath & CSV(S) & ".csv""),[Delimiter="";"", Columns=" & CountCols & ", Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""De eerste rij als veldnamen gebruiken"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Bron, [PromoteAllScalars=true])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & ColTypes

' Check if sheet exists or create/copy one
Dim exists As Boolean
exists = False
For SE = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Sheets(SE).Name = Sh(S) Then
        exists = True
    End If
Next SE
If exists = True Then
    Sheets(Sh(S)).Activate
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BLANCO").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BLANCO (2)").Name = Sh(S)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sh(S)).Visible = True
    Sheets(Sh(S)).Activate
End If
Sheets(Sh(S)).Range("A1").Value = ShT(S)

' Fill sheet with data
With Sheets(Sh(S)).ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & CSV(S) & ";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$4")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & CSV(S) & "]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = CSV(S)
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False ' <------ Highlights after error 1004
End With
```

I use a Dutch version of Excel, that's why some code and checks are in Dutch.
Hope some can help me with this (t)error...

Comment: Since it isn't possible to test your code without considerable effort, it'll be guesses. Here is such a guess: This looks wrong: `"" & Chr(13) & """" & Chr(10) & ""`. You are putting a quote between CR and LF. Put a vbCrLF there instead. There are more issues of similar kind

Comment: There are a lot of string building issues here.  Add a line `MsgBox ColTypes` and examine the result, you will see what's wrong

Comment: Do you actually **need** InStr? It looks to me that *Width* or *Length* would be the complete field name; not a part of a longer string representing the field name.

Comment: @pnuts This isn't the entire code, I create some variables before and check the witch CSV it is. But that doesn't seem necessary to me to show here...

Comment: @Sam This is the way I got it by recording a macro while creating a query

Comment: @chrisneilsen I tried, got exactly the same code as I recorded, but the created doesn't work...

Comment: @Jeeped Normally Width and Length are complete field names, but users can create other field names in the software where the CSV's are compiled. Therefor I have to look "InStr". I like the code you have given below, will use that, thanks! Double quotes are needed, I think, because the show up by a recorded macro...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *height, length, volume*, etc are only **part** of a longer string that represents the field name, there still may be a better way to use InStr to determine field type.

```
For ct = LBound(ColNames) To UBound(ColNames)
    select case true
        case cbool(InStr(ColNames(CT), "Kilo") + InStr(ColNames(CT), "kg") + _
                   InStr(ColNames(CT), "Ton") + InStr(ColNames(CT), "Gewicht") + _
                   InStr(ColNames(CT), "Volume") + InStr(ColNames(CT), "Area") + _
                   InStr(ColNames(CT), "Oppervlak"))
            ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type number}, "
        case cbool(InStr(ColNames(CT), "Width") + InStr(ColNames(CT), "Breedte") + _
                   InStr(ColNames(CT), "Length") + InStr(ColNames(CT), "Lengte") + _
                   InStr(ColNames(CT), "Perimeter") + InStr(ColNames(CT), "Height") + _
                   InStr(ColNames(CT), "Hoogte"))
            ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", Int64.Type}, "
        case else
            ColTypes = ColTypes & "{""""" & ColNames(CT) & """"", type text}, "
    end select
next ct
ColTypes = Left(ColTypes, Len(ColTypes) - 2)
...
```

btw, those InStr's are defaulted to vbBinaryCompare which is a case-sensitive comparison.

btw², did you really intend to wrap the field names in double-double quotes? e.g.:

```
{""fieldname1"", Int64.Type}, {""fieldname2"", type number}, {""fieldname3"", type text}
```